# Find matching items in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a loop that grabs a user inputted number (no_reps) and inserts certain information based on that.

For example if a user inputs the number 3, a number between 1 and 3 will be inserted in r.repetition_index.

What i'm looking to do is match each of those unique numbers for each loop and insert the treatment_indexes variable so for each r.repetition_index, it doesn't repeat the same number.

For example, my table results would be as such, excluding treatment_index.

```
|id|treatment_selection_id|repetition_index|treatment_index|
|1 |         1            |       1        |               |
|2 |         1            |       2        |               |
|3 |         1            |       3        |               |
|4 |         2            |       1        |               |
|5 |         2            |       2        |               |
|6 |         2            |       3        |               |
|7 |         3            |       1        |               |
|8 |         3            |       2        |               |
|9 |         3            |       3        |               |
```

Notice how every `treatment_selection_id` has a unique repetition_index of 1..3. Now for every `repetition_index` that equals 1 I want to insert a unique number of 1..3 in `treatment_index` and so forth with repetition_index 2 and 3.

So far I have the following, but `r.treatment_index` isn't inserting unique number for each matching `r.repetition_index`.

```
no_reps = @trial.number_of_repetitions
@trial.treatment_selections.each do |r|
 r.repetitions.in_groups_of(no_reps).each_with_index do |a, i|
   treatment_indexes = (1..no_reps).to_a.shuffle
   a.each_with_index do |r, j|
     r.repetition_index = j + 1
     r.treatment_index = treatment_indexes[j]
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: did you hit save on your `@trial`? Because in this code you only update the memory object and not the database table object.

Comment: Yes @trial is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the next group is iterated, a new array of random `treatment_indexes` will be created, sou you are leaving to random the order they are distributed in the `treatment_selecion_id` level. In your results, you should see that `treatment_selecion_id`s with the same number will have different `treatment_index`. But you couldn't find a uniqueness relation between `repetition_index` and `treatment_index`.

You could create this `treatment_index` randomly but you still need to search for the appearances of `repetition_index` and avoid collisions. Notice that if you do not create this indexes randomly, you could end up with `treatment_selection_id` and `treatment_index` having the same values and that would comply the uniqueness behavior you are asking for.

This change should give you randomness and still eliminate duplicates in the `repetition_index` level.

```
no_reps = @trial.number_of_repetitions
repet_treat = {} # you have to keep track of repetition_indexes and treatment_indexes
@trial.treatment_selections.each do |r|
 r.repetitions.in_groups_of(no_reps).each_with_index do |a, i|
   treatment_indexes = (1..no_reps).to_a # randomness will be handled elsewhere
   a.each_with_index do |r, j|
     r.repetition_index = j + 1
     # store treatment_index for this repetition_index in an array
     repeat_treat[r.repetition_index] ||= [] 
     # get the treatment_index you have already used for this repetition_index
     used_treat_indexes = repeat_treat[r.repetition_index]
     # delete the used indexes from the posibilities of the next and get a new random index
     r.treatment_index = (treatment_indexes - used_treat_indexes).sample
     # store your newely used treatment_index in its repetition_index group
     repeat_treat[r.repetition_index] << r.treatment_index
   end
  end
end
```

The structure of `@trial` is already storing `treatment_index`, so you should be able to implement the same idea using `@trial` instead of a new hash.

```
no_reps = @trial.number_of_repetitions
@trial.treatment_selections.each do |r|
 r.repetitions.in_groups_of(no_reps).each_with_index do |a, i|
   treatment_indexes = (1..no_reps).to_a # still handle randomness elsehwere
   a.each_with_index do |r, j|
     r.repetition_index = j + 1
     used_indexes = @trial
                      .treatment_selections
                      .map(&:repetitions)
                      .select { |rep| rep.repetition_index == r.repetition_index }
                      .map(&:treatment_index)
     r.treatment_index = (treatment_indexes - used_indexes).sample
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a well executed solution. Appreciated. One more question though. What if I have two variables to consider?  For example...

r.repetitions.in_groups_of(3).each_with_index do |a, i|
  treatment_indexes = (1..4).to_a

Comment: If the treatment_indexes length depend on something outside the loop, you should initialize it next to ‘no_reps=‘ otherwise you create the same thing over again, as you can see, that array never changes. If it depends on something inside each iteration it will work fine as long as you dont run out of treatment_indexes. If you need more indexes, try enlarging the array from the beginning or just adding 1 to the largest that is already used.

Comment: Great. Thanks again for your help. Got me out of a bind.